# RD Gateway to connect to windows 2000 terminal server

Tags: windows-2000, windows-terminal-services

We have a legacy product that end users access by connecting to a windows 2000 terminal server on our premises.   To circumvent corporate firewall issues on the end user side,  we have a Citrix Gateway (which tunnels the RDP traffic over HTTPS), for them to use.

Is it possible to replace the Citrix layer with RD Gateway 2008 (or 2008 R2)?

Specifically I am looking to find out 
a) Can RD Gateway 2008 can act as the gateway for a Windows 2000 terminal server.
b) Can we do this without forcing our users to enter their credentials twice - once for the gateway and again for the Windows 2000 terminal server

Appreciate any insights/comments.